# Change event type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to get the type of change of an element.

```
<input type="text" onchange="fn()"/>

<script>

function fn() {
    if (event.isKeyPress) 
        // do something
    else if (event.isClick)
        //do something else

</script>
```

So in full, I'm changing a text field, then to change, the user has to unfocus the field and change its contents. I want to find the manner at which it was unfocused (e.g. by <kbd>tab</kbd> or click). Is this possible?

NOTE:
I am using jQuery.

Comment: focusout doesnt give me the type of event it is (meaning if it is click or keypress etc)

Comment: just google about event.which and within that do focusout .......

Comment: that is perfect apart from that I need it to be in one event type (thats why I chose onchange() )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a keydown event on your input, you can trig the focusout event if the pressed key is "tab" and do what you want.
Else the focusout will be triggered by a clic.

Comment: Yes, perfect but want that in a single event function

Comment: I don't think it's possible in a single event.
I found nothing in the event object returned by a focusout or blur jquery event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keydown.  See: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/onkeydown.htm or http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').focus(function(){

   // something..

}).change(function(){ // or keyup

   // do something awesome

}).focusout(function(){

  // that's it

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input" ).focusout(function() {
    // do something
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

https://api.jquery.com/focusin/

http://api.jquery.com/focus/